# PHP Help Gallery

Tags: php, html, css

Hi i need some help with some php, i am very new to it so go easy, my friend made me a pdf tutorial on how to create an image gallery, and I have followed step by step but seem to have a different result, which even my friend can't seem to find. HTML:

```
<?php 

include_once ("scripts/connection.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
<h1>Website</h1>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" title="home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.php" title="register">register</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php" title="gallery">gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>

<div class="container">

<?php

if(isset($_GET["id"])){

    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<h2>" . $row["title"] . "</h2>";
    echo "<div class='full' style='background:url(" . $row["url"] . ");      background-size:cover;'></div>";
    echo "<p>" . $row["description"] . "</p>";
    echo "<p><a href='gallery.php' title=‘close'>close</a></p>";
    }
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<a class='preview' title='see full image' href='?id=" .          $row["id"] . "'>";
    echo "<div class='thumbnail' style='background:url(" . $row["url"]   . "); background-size:cover;’></div>";
    echo "<div class='title'>" . $row["title"] . "</div>";
    echo "</a>";

    }
    ?>


</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php 

mysqli_close($dbconnect);

?>
```

CSS:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body{
font-family:sans-serif;
 }

header{
text-align:center;
box-shadow:0 3px 5px #DDDDDD;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 5px #DDDDDD;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 5px #DDDDDD;
}

h1{
font-weight:lighter;
font-size:2.5em;
line-height:2em;
}

nav ul li{
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
line-height: 3em;
padding: 0 20px;
}

a, a:visited{
text-decoration: none;
color: #2A80B9;
}

a:hover, a:active{
color: #3598DC;
}

.container{
width: 70%;
margin: 50px auto;
}

.preview{
display: inline-block;
width:20%;
margin:40px 0 0 4%;
font-size:0;
}

.preview:hover{
box-shadow:0 5px 7px #BBBBBB;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 7px #BBBBBB;
-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 7px #BBBBBB;
}

.thumbnail{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}

.title{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 2.5em;
background:#222222;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: -2.5em;
color: white;
opacity: 0.75;
filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}

.preview:hover .title{
opacity:1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.full{
width:100%;
height: 500px;
}
```

First of all thank you for reading, and if you take a look at the code you will realise that the middle picture is missing, thats a database problem which i can fix the real issue is the thumbnail text which does not show for some reason.

Image 1 is my current result: [image: current result]

Image 2 is my freinds finished result, what it should look like: [image: what it should be like]

Thank you guys in advance for the help.

Comment: The problem looks like you just have a missing URL in your DB !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works like your friends example so why your version does not is peculiar ~ this is virtually identical to your original posting, just some minor alterations but nothing IMO that would affect the output. Is the css in your included `styles.css` exactly 100% the same as that quoted in your question? Is there possibly something in the javascript that removes divs with class `title` or is hiding it?

```
<?php 
    $host   =   'localhost';
    $uname  =   'xxxx'; 
    $pwd    =   'xxxx'; 
    $db     =   'xxxx';
    $conn=new mysqli( $host, $uname, $pwd, $db );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Website</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php" title="home">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="register.php" title="register">register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.php" title="gallery">gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
        <?php

            if( isset( $_GET["id"] ) ){
                $id = $_GET["id"];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = '$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $result ) ){
                     echo "
                     <h2>" . $row->title . "</h2>
                     <div class='full' style='background:url(" . $row->url . ");background-size:cover;'></div>
                     <p>" . $row->description . "</p>
                     <p><a href='gallery.php' title='close'>close</a></p>";
                }
                mysqli_free_result( $result );
            }



            $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
            $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $result ) ){
                echo "
                <a class='preview' title='see full image' href='?id=" . $row->id . "'>
                    <div class='thumbnail' style='background:url(" . $row->url   . "); background-size:cover;'></div>
                    <div class='title'>" . $row->title . "</div>
                </a>";
            }
            mysqli_free_result( $result );
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I know its very strange, my friend is sending me the original code so i will copy it out exactly to see if it helps